# How can i set English as default language for my app?

Tags: ios, localization

I have an app with localization strings. I'm supporting two languages that English and Turkish. My language strings works correctly. However, if i pick Spanish, Deutsch or any other language, it's running in Turkish. But in my base Localizable.strings(base) file, there are English strings not Turkish. How can i do that, if i do not supporting that language run application as English ?